# run time analysis of loop within a loop

Tags: c++

In case,there is loop within a loop in code. Does using a function for accomplishing the task of inner loop,really can decrease the amount of time taken by the program to run?
Instead of

```
for i=0 to i=upper limit {
    for j=0 to j= less than or equal to upper limit {code here}
```

using

```
for i=0 to i=upper limit  
    function(); (call a function which contains the innner for loop)
```

will this help anything in optimizing the code?

Comment: I don't think so. even it will add the overhead of function calling, stack allocation etc.

Comment: Why do you think it would? Can you explain the context of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *hide* complexity in a function with something like:

```
for x = 1 to N
    doSomethingXTimes(x)
```

The fact that `doSomethingXTimes()` is dependent on `N` means that the whole thing is `O(n2)`, becaue you're executing `N * N` (or some value proportional to that) steps.

Comment: thankx for answering my question,it was so stupid of me to think about this.Still,m glad i got it.

Answer (score 0):

No this will not optimize your code as far as algorithmic complexity is concerned.

Also, by using a function within the outer for loop, you will only increase the number of function calls made in your code and make it even slower. (You could make the function inline though)